# Spring security baisc authentication only validating first request

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using spring basic authentication with a custom authentication provider:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
}
```

And

```
    @Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    String name = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

    if (customauth()) { // use the credentials
        // and authenticate against the third-party system
        {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    name, password, new ArrayList<>());
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class
    );
}
```

To test this I'm using postman with the following tests:

invalid credentials -> 401 unauthorized

correct credentials -> 200 OK

invalid credentials -> 200 OK

My problem is that the last request should return 401 unauthorized and every following request after a successful login is 200 OK even with a wrong token and without token.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what did you have in your customauth() method? you can try to see this exemple : https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-security-rest-basic-auth and try compara with your code if you have ommit something. for now the only thing i see is that you don t have authenticationEntryPoint but i don know if its really needed but you can try :  .httpBasic()
          .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);

Answer (score 1):

When you logged in successfully, Spring Security will create an `Authentication` object and will put it in `SecurityContext` in your HTTP session. As far as you have a valid session with a valid `Authentication` object at the server, Spring Security won't authenticate your request again and will use the `Authentication` object saved in your session.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Spring Security feature, see [SEC-53](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-53?redirect=false):

> Check the SecurityContextHolder for an authenticated Authentication and reuse it in that case, do not call the authentication manager again.

If you like to reauthenticate, you could

- use no session at all
- logout before reauthenticate

In both cases Spring Security will not find an authenticated user saved in the session and will use the new username and password for authentication.